# Will the lack of an entry stamp for return to Nepal from India be a problem for me at US CBP?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, india, nepal

I am a Nepalese citizen, currently in Nepal from 10th March.  I have not been in India for the past 14 days, the only time I was in India was from 2nd March to 10th March and I will be departing from Nepal to USA, on May 17th, but my visa was issued in Mumbai consulate, India. So here is my present scenario.

While flying from Kathmandu to Delhi, my passport was stamped as "Departed from Nepal" (at TIA airport) and "Arrived in Delhi" (at Delhi airport). But while coming back, at the Siliguri-Kakarvitta border, no one asked and I could enter Nepal without stamping my passport, as we have open border and we don't need visa to enter the both countries. I took the road route from Siliguri (India) to Kakarvitta (Nepal), on 10th March: first I flew from Mumbai to Delhi to Bagdora, Siliguri)

I do have the flight boarding pass and ticket confirmation for my flight from Mumbai to Delhi to Bagdora and then a domestic flight from Bhadrapur airport, Nepal on 10th March. I also obtained No Objection Certificate in person on March 24th from the Ministry of Nepal to continue my study after I arrived back from land border to Nepal. I also have stamped the currency exchanged by me on April 8th from a bank in Nepal in my passport which also proves my presence here in Nepal. I have been and I am currently in Nepal from March 10th.

But since my visa has been issued in Mumbai consulate and my course start date is on June 20th, will I have any problem with CBP at the US border due to the lack of entry stamp to Nepal? Or due to the current presidential proclamation?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that is a requirement to prove that you haven't been to one of the countries subject to a geographic COVID-19 ban within the last 14 days, beyond your declaration that you haven't been there. If the need for proof comes up, you can try to find any receipt or appointment notice from Nepal, or anything else that places you in Nepal between your return to Nepal and 14 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common to not get entry and/or exit stamps for all countries you visit.

Sometimes the people are just lazy, sometimes they forget, sometimes they're too busy and just wave you through. And sometimes there's no way to get stamps at all as you never see an actual person (thinking of the ever more common automated border entry points where you shove your passport in a reader and the machine checks it to your fingerprint and photo).

I've for example not had an entry stamp for my home country, EVER, nor an exit stamp.
Same for many countries I've visited. And I've never had a problem visiting anywhere as a result (in fact the only minor problem I've ever had was when my passport was damaged abroad, on returning home I was reminded to replace it as technically it was invalidated because of a small tear the checkin desk who'd damaged it had fixed with sticky tape).

Comment: In the list of possible reasons for not getting a stamp, you've omitted the reason that explains why you don't have any stamps from you home country (if my recollection of your nationality is correct): the country's immigration regulations may prohibit the stamping of certain passports.

Comment: @phoog true, hadn't occurred to me. My dad did have stamps from our own country but they were rare. Probably border agents accidentally stamping him in after a long line of foreigners.